Distance Correlation vs Mutual Information for non-linear relationship between features
I am working on getting non-linear relationships between Amount (dependent variable) and other features(independent variables). So far I have used Distance correlation and Mutual Information. But when comparing, some features have aligned values of distance correlation and mutual information but some features have very different values. This confuses me that which score distance corr or Mutual Information should I choose to describe the strength of relationship between the variables. I am sharing the below data for reference:
Here Non-linear_corr is the distance correlation and Non-linear_micorr is the mutual information value. Current dataframe is sorted by Non-linear_corr values in descending order.


From a theoretical perspective, MI is the ideal choice. This is because other dependence measures (such as distance correlation) are typically biased towards specific types of relationships, while MI is generally "equitable" and can capture any form of dependence (see Kinney and Atwal 2014 for further discussion).
However, in practice, accurately estimating MI can be challenging, and how you choose to estimate MI can greatly affect your results. If your data is continuous and 1-dimensional, a good choice for estimation is the KSG nearest-neighbor MI estimator (you can find a python implementation here). If your data is high-dimensional, it is much more difficult to estimate MI, but some options exist (see this approach or this approach). I would strongly discourage binning approaches which tend to be less reliable than the KSG estimator.
If you cannot reliably estimate MI for your data (perhaps you don't have many data points, or the dimensionality is very high), it might make sense to use other approaches such as distance correlation.

Hello Thank you for the answer! My data is 1 dimensional and continuous. I checked the python library you shared but I could not found any method to estimate MI for 2 continuous variables. I also checked the documentation. Can you tell me the method I need to use if it is available for x and y both continuous?

Sure! The NPEET library I linked to will estimate the MI of two continuous variables $I(X; Y)$. In particular, you can look at the second code block of the readme file. The function you want to use is ee.mi(x, y). Hope this helps!

Hello, thank you for the reply. I tried the same formulae but unfortunately i am not getting proper results. For all the different x,y combinations (x varies, y is same) I am getting the same value keeping other parameters same (k, alpha as default). What might be the reason, as it does not make sense to have same values for all x,y combinations.

It's hard to know without seeing the exact code/data, but it sounds like it could be a bug in your code. Perhaps you could post another question with more details?
